# How to Programmatically Modify Java Source Code

Tags: java

I am going to need the ability to programmatically modify Java source code, specifically apply refactorings. For example moving a method from one class to another, changing an access modifier from public to private, etc.

Now in C# I'd probably go the abstract syntax tree / Roslyn approach, but I have no idea where to even begin in Java.

Given a java source code file, how does one parse it so that modifications can be made and then saved to it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: This looks to just be reading a file. I am not going to want to just read in a java file and look for specific strings (e.g. public void method). I need not only to read the file in, but presumably parse it into an AST?

Answer (score 0):

**First**: Things like that (called **refactoring**) are already handled by a good Java IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, NetBeans and you name it). I really think that stuff like that should be handled by an IDE.

**Second**: If you really want to edit the files programmatically keep in mind that you're the one who is in charge of format and syntax. You have to read the files, edit them (cut out, paste in or add some code at proper line) and save them. The link provided from VedX is a good start for basic IO. But there is so much more to keep track of.

I did something similar with OpenEdge ABL and it is no easy task (you'll find things that went wrong you never thought of and if you didn't backed up your code it's f**ked up). I've got it done but in the end it wasn't a good trade-off between time spend to get it done and actual usefullness (I just needed it about 4 times for approx. 1500 files).

Finally (after I lost many hours inventing the wheel of refactoring) I wrote some class generators which wrote a whole new file evertime I needed to change something - lastly I only changed the class generators (maybe this is something you didn't thought of and it fits too). Now it's automatized and generic and could run in parallel (something what OpenEdge isn't designed for - okay it's a cheap hack by me).

**Third**: Maybe there is a package you can use in your Java project. I would try to Google it. My first attempt resulted in this: http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=4 for first understanding what it's all about and what to consider.

Comment: I think ANTLR (http://www.antlr.org/api/JavaTool/index.html) is going to be the solution. I can see they have a Java grammar and lets you walk ASTs.